# springboot app looking for GenericResponseService bean

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I am new to springboot.

Doing a migration of my service (kotlin)following a guide written at work.
Got this weird exception and cannot find any documentation.

```
Parameter 3 of method multipleOpenApiResource in org.springdoc.webflux.core.MultipleOpenApiSupportConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springdoc.core.GenericResponseService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springdoc.core.GenericResponseService' in your configuration.
```

Should I define this bean at my `@Configuration`?
Is this a symptom of dependency missing or bad dependency wiring?

Comment: sounds like (identic error message) https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1357

Comment: I had a bean called ResponseBuilder that conflicted with spring boot. renamed it

Comment: You can post (&accept) answers to your own questions!;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my beans was called ResponseBuilder and it conflicted with spring boot.
Sorry for the trouble